# Formulario de contacto php

Tags: php, email

Tengo un formulario de contacto, el problema es que no envía el mensaje, ya he mirado en spam y demás y no tengo ni idea porqué no lo envía

Os pongo el código. (para realizar las pruebas, lo subo a un servidor de hostinger)

**contacto.php**

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$para = "miEmail@gmail.com";
$titulo = "CONTACTO DESDE WEB"; 
$headers = array("From: " .$email,
    "Reply-To: miEmail@gmail.com",
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
);
$headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);
$msjCorreo = "Nombre:" .$nombre ."\n E-Mail:" .$email ."\n Mensaje:\n"                   .$mensaje;

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (@mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $headers)) {
        echo "
        <script language='javascript'>
        alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
        window.location.href =     'http://..web../index.html#contact';
        </script>";
    } else {
        echo "
        <script language='javascript'>
        alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
        window.location.href = 'Falló el envio';
        </script>";
    }
}
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 wow fadeInUp delay-05s">
    <div class="form">
        <form action="contacto.php" method="post">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" name="nombre" value="Nombre y apellidos *" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
            <input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="E-mail *" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
            <textarea class="input-text text-area" name="mensaje" cols="0" rows="0" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Mensaje *</textarea>
            <input class="input-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola! No recordaba para qué era el uso del arroba en el código, y refrescando mi memoria con una búsqueda, veo que es para suprimir mensajes de error.
Te convendría llamar a la función `mail`, pero sin la arroba, porque igual y está generando un error que no se despliega por lo mismo.
Tal vez también deberías colocar el código en un bloque *try/catch* para controlar el error.

Saludos.

Te dejo la liga del [arroba](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: ya lo probé también sin la arroba y obtengo el mismo resultado, de hecho la arroba la puse después viendo algunos códigos que la tenían y por probar... no obstante no conocía para que se usa, simplemente probé con ella, gracias por la información

Answer (score 1):

Debes de retirar el `@` de la función `mail`, aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
<?php
 $to = "ejemplo@ejemplo.com, ejemplo@ejemplo.com";
 $subject = "HTML email";

 $message = "
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>mi correo</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>Esto funciona :)</p>

 </body>
 </html>
 ";


 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

 $headers .= 'Cc: ejemplo@ejemplo.com' . "\r\n";

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
 ?>
```

Pásate por la [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp) ;)

Comment: He probado los ejemplos tal cual, solo cambiando la dirección de envio del email y ni así funciona, en el servidor tenía la versión de php 5.5 y he actualizado a la versión 7 y en ninguna de las dos versiones funciona, la verdad es que es bastante raro pero no tengo ni idea de lo que pasa

Comment: Es muy raro, hace tiempo use el ejemplo que te muestro y es muy simple y funcional,  me suena a un error humano .-.

Comment: pues bueno, me ha dado por cambiar el email (era de gmail) a uno de hotmail, y para el de hotmail funciona... he hecho la prueba con los dos emails tal y como aparece en tu ejemplo y solo llegan al de hotmail, es una cosa bastante rara, pero no se porqué... sabes si hay que configurar algo en gmail o algo similar? (por supuesto he mirado en la carpeta de spam, asi como en estas de social y promociones que tiene por defecto) No obstante muchas gracias por tu ayuda, un saludo

Comment: .-. Yo utilicé una cuenta de Gmail y no, no hay que configurar nada.

Answer (score 1):

Una forma super facil de hacerlo es con PHPMailer

```
require_once "PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$mail = $_POST['email'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$para = "miEmail@gmail.com";
$titulo = "CONTACTO DESDE WEB"; 
$email = new PHPMailer;
$email->isSMTP();
$email->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  //Servidor de correo saliente en este caso gmail
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->Username = 'miEmail@gmail.com';                 
$email->Password = 'pass';                          
$email->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            
$email->Port = 465;      

$email->From = $mail; //quien envia el correo
$email->FromName = $nombre; //Nombre de quien lo envie
$email->Subject = $titulo; //Titulo
$email->Body = $mensaje; //Aquí todo el contenido del mensaje
$email->AddAddress($para); //la direccion para quien es el correo
if (!$email->Send()) {
    echo $email->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "Se envio";
}
```

**La librería la encuentras [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)**